# Sometimes I see Tensorflow session.run fetch only the optimizer, sometimes it fetches both the optimizer and cost. What's the difference?

Tags: tensorflow

Sometimes I see

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed)
```

other times

```
sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)
```

As far as I know, the session.run will calculate the item that is fetched, and will also calculate everything that depends on the item which is fetched. Since the optimizer is dependent on 'cost', isn't it redundant to call both the cost and the optimizer in the latter example?

Typically the optimizer is defined something like

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the optimizer is dependent on 'cost', isn't it redundant to call both the cost and the optimizer in the latter example?

You're wrong about one thing: optimizer does not necessarily depend on 'cost'. Therefore it's not redundant to add cost to the fetch list. The two calls do not execute the same graph. The other answer is also wrong on this.

A simple example: let's say your `cost = tf.square(W)`. The gradients w.r.t W is just `2 * W` which does not depend on the cost. Therefore the `optimizer.minize(cost)` operation in the graph (which updates `W` with the gradients) does not depend on the cost. This might seem strange given that you do need to provided the cost tensor to the optimizer -- but the tensor will not necessarily be evaluated.

As for the practical reason why people would do `sess.run([cost, opt])` instead of `sess.run(opt)`, it's probably just for logging (printing the cost value).

Comment: Wow, never thought of this before! Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `optimizer` in `sess.run()` allows you to update the parameters. From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize), `AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)`returns

> An Operation that updates the variables in var_list

Thus:

- `sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed)`- only updates the weights˜
- `sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)` - update weights AND returns the cost.